# Is it possible to load local html pages into Gamemaker games?

Tags: html5, web, game-maker

I was just wondering if it would be possible somehow to load locally saved web pages into a game. My primary use for them would be as menus, helping to navigate between rooms.

I know about the built in "Open URL" function but I want to know if the loaded page can interact with the actual game.

Comment: I don't know what sort of dll binding and surface manipultation the newest Game Maker allows, but you could look at [Awesomium](http://awesomium.com/). It works really well.

Answer (score 1):

No. (Certainly not without external DLLs anyway.)

HTML is only a mark-up language — to actually see a page, you need an HTML renderer. Game Maker doesn't have one.

It would be possible to open a locally rendered web page in a browser and use local storage to save files to disk which you could then load from Game Maker, but that's a *really* long way around!

Consider [making your own menus](http://www.ehow.com/how_6188210_make-menu-game-maker.html), using an existing menu system [like this one](http://gmc.yoyogames.com/index.php?showtopic=424539) or learning to make web-based games.